# How to set OnCheckedChangeListener to a checkbox of a cell in a listview

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, oncheckedchanged

Hi guys I am trying to set an `OnCheckedChangeListener` on a `CheckBox` declared in the `xml` file that represent the single row of the `ListView` (**item_todo.xml**), here the code of the checkbox:

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="" />
```

Here the part of code of the listview (**fragment_bacheca.xml**):

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
```

Then I use a custom adapter:`

```
public class TaskListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<TaskCell>{

    public TaskListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<TaskCell> objects){
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_todo, null);
        TextView task_subject = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.task_subject);
        TextView task_type = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.task_type);
        TextView task_data = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.task_data);
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

        TaskCell t = getItem(position);
        task_subject.setText(t.getMateria());
        task_type.setText(t.getTipo());
        task_data.setText(t.getData());
        if(t.getFatto().equals("1")) {
            cb.setChecked(true);
            task_subject.setPaintFlags(task_subject.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
        }
        else{
            cb.setChecked(false);
        }

        return convertView;
    }
```

`TaskCell` is the class for the the data of the **todo_item**.

And here the code of the fragment where I call the listener:

```
taskView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_todo, null);
    checkbox_task = (CheckBox) taskView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

    checkbox_task.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

    list = new LinkedList<>();
    adapter = new TaskListAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.item_todo, list);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

The problem is that nothing happened and with the debug i saw that the `onCheckedChanged` is never reached.

Anyone knows why? Thank you all

Comment: It may not be the reason, but you've mentioned `todo_item.xml` as the filename in the problem description, but I see `item_todo` in the code.  I can't see `todo_item.xml` in the code.

Comment: I made a mistake in the explanation, I intend item_todo.xml

Comment: `OnCheckedChangeListener()` should be implemented inside the adapter instead of fragment.

Comment: if I implement it on the adapter the process execute the onCheckedChanged (i saw it through the debug) but the checkbox still remain unchecked and nothing happens...

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement the adapter class with ViewHolder pattern like this,

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_todo, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
        ...
        ...
        holder.cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                buttonView.setChecked(isChecked);
            }
        });
        ... 
        ...
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    // Get the data item for this position
    TaskCell t = getItem(position);
    ...
    ...
    if(t.getFatto().equals("1")) {
        holder.cb.setChecked(true);
    } else {
        holder.cb.setChecked(false);
    }
    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    ...
    ...
    CheckBox cb;

    ViewHolder(View v) {
        checkBox = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
    }
}
```